# Difference between Association and Dispatch

Tags: associations, rule

In the example below, `Association` has a different behavior from `Dispatch`:

```
{1, 2, 3} /. Association@{1 -> "test",2 -> "test" , _Integer -> Null}
{1, 2, 3} /. Dispatch@{1 -> "test" ,2 -> "test" , _Integer -> Null}
```

> ```
> {"test", "test", 3}
> {"test", "test", Null}
> ```

The pattern `_Integer -> Null` is not applied on the first case.

**The question is**: There is some way to efficiently make `Association` behave like `Dispatch`? Or `Dispatch` is the best solution for this case?

PS: this is a toy code, my original list if much bigger and used a lot o times, so a hash table is necessary.

Comment: `Association` keys cannot be patterns (they behave like they had `Verbatim`), that's the main difference with common rules. Try `_Integer /. Association@{_Integer -> Null}`, you will get the `Null` value.

Comment: If you are not going to change your list of rules after you construct them, `Dispatch` is pretty good. The main difference is that it is cheap to add new key-value pairs to associations, constructing new associations - not so with `Dispatch`. You can somewhat emulate the action of `Dispatch`-ed rules on a list of elements, by using `Lookup` with `Associations`. `Lookup` can take a list of keys. It has also optional argument for a default value. Not sure if it can do both at the same time, don't remember.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, on this subject, the FTC is planning for microsec resolution for Nasdaq ("Tape C") transaction stream. In a few large hospitals there are ~10k RTLS+RFID tags on which real time monitoring is desired - coupled w/ ParallelCombine and GroupBy tasks - can Association and Dispatch scale up to these real time analytics challenges (think visulization like Tableau).

Comment: ... or would have to rebuild on Erlang.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin nice, it works!.. `Lookup[Association@{1 -> "test", 2 -> "test"}, {1, 2, 3}, Null]` do the work. I believe you should answer this.

Comment: @alancalvitti Can't say, too little information. `Associations` can hold millions of key-value pairs easily, but are not too memory-efficient. It all depends on how large the total number of key-value pairs is, and whether or not it is feasible to store them in an `Association` in memory. There are other factors too.

Comment: @Murta Ok, done as requested.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

#### General

If you are not going to change your list of rules after you construct them, `Dispatch` is pretty good. From the user's viewpoint, the main difference is that it is cheap to add new key-value pairs to associations, or remove existing ones, constructing new associations. Not so with `Dispatch` - once you obtained the `Dispatch`-ed set of rules, you can't really change the rule set efficiently. OTOH, you can apply `Dispatch`-ed rules to any expression (and at any level) efficiently, while `Association`s are more limited here - you can only extract the values for keys. So, these constructs generally have different sets of use cases, which however do have a significant overlap.

#### The case of duplicate keys

As Istvan noted in comments, there are important differences in semantics between rule lists / `Dispatch` and `Association`s, in the way they treat duplicate keys.

The first one is that, while in rule application (with or without `Dispatch`), the rule is that "the first one wins" (since rules are applied left to right), for  `Association`s the rule is that "the last one wins", since the key-value pair which occurs later in the rule list, overwrites the earlier entries with the same key.

So, in particiular:

```
ClearAll[a];
a /. {a -> 0, a -> 1}
Lookup[{a -> 0, a -> 1}, a]
Lookup[<|a -> 0, a -> 1|> , a]

(*
    0
    0
    1
*)
```

The second difference is that in fact, while lists of rules, and also `Dispatch`, actually do store all rules, even if normally only the first matching one is used, `Associations` never store more than one rule for a given key: all earlier key-value pairs are eliminated at association construction time, and only the last entry remains.

This may matter in some cases. Sometime we may want to get the results of all possible rule applications, e.g. with `ReplaceList`:

```
ReplaceList[a, {a -> 0, a -> 1}]

(* {0, 1} *)
```

This will also work for `Dispatch`- ed rules, but not for `Association`s, for reasons I just outlined.

#### Using `Lookup` to emulate `Dispatch` with `Association`

You can somewhat emulate the action of `Dispatch`-ed rules on a list of elements, by using `Lookup` with `Association`s. `Lookup` can take a list of keys. It has also optional argument for a default value. So, you can do

```
Lookup[Association@{1 -> "test", 2 -> "test"}, {1, 2, 3}, Null]

(* {"test", "test", Null}  *)
```

We can now make a quick comparison for larger volumes of data:

```
assocLrg = AssociationThread[Range[1000000] -> Range[1000000] + 1];
dispatchedLarge = 
   Dispatch[Append[Thread[Range[1000000] -> Range[1000000] + 1], _Integer -> Null]];
```

The space they occupy is the same:

```
ByteCount[dispatchedLarge]

(* 116390576 *)

ByteCount[assocLrg]

(* 116390368 *)
```

It might be an indication that `Dispatch` has been reimplemented to use `Association`s under the hood, or it might not. In any case, their key extraction speeds are comparable:

```
Range[100000] /. dispatchedLarge; // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.073587, Null} *)

Lookup[assocLrg, Range[100000], Null]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.041016, Null} *)
```

It may look as if `Dispatch` is much slower, but let's not forget that `ReplaceAll` is a pretty imprecise operation. We now use `Replace` with level 1:

```
Replace[Range[100000], dispatchedLarge, {1}]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.047408, Null} *)
```

and observe the timing in the same range as for associations, if a tiny bit slower.

In the case where you don't need to change the set of key-value pairs after it has been constructed, it is probably more a matter of personal preferences which one to use, at least at the time of this writing.

#### Summary

`Association`s and `Dispatch`ed rules are not the same constructs, although their use cases do have a significant overlap. For such uses, they are more or less speed - equivalent, as have the same memory efficiency as well.

They also have significant differences, both in semantics and in their sets of use cases, so one can't fully replace one with the other in all cases. As always, which one to use depends on the problem at hand. However, many cases where in the past `Dispatch` was the only way to get efficient solutions, are done conceptually cleaner with `Association`s.

Comment: @Murta Just a sidenote: there is a **huge** difference between rule-lists and associations when used in `Lookup`, though it only manifests if there are redundant keys. `Association` automatically removes those, keeping the last one, leading to `{Lookup[{a -> First, b -> 0, a -> Last}, a], Lookup[<|a -> First, b -> 0, a -> Last|>, a]}` returning `{First, Last}`.

Comment: @IstvánZachar This is an important point, thanks. I have updated my answer, adding a section on this.

Answer (score 10):

The most direct way is to create a dispatch table from your association when you need this behavior:

```
{1, 2, 3} /. Dispatch[Association[{1 -> "test", 2 -> "test", _Integer -> Null}]]

(* {"test", "test", Null} *)
```

Comment: Interesting, tks +1

Comment: @Daniel W, as `Associations` are also based on optimized structures, eg hash trees, is there any efficiency advantage to create a `Dispatch` version?

Comment: @alancalvitti, I suspect `Dispatch` is more efficient because its structure is optimized for rapid replacement, but I have not tested it. I think of this usage as an explicit typecast of an association to a dispatch table, which makes my intent clear. The use of an association in `ReplaceAll` is not documented; we only suspected it would work in the first place because the input form is a list of rules. Since `Association` is atomic, I worry about this working in the future, but the explicit typecast of `Normal` or `Dispatch` future-proofs my code.