# ParallelMemberQ

Tags: parallelization, expression-test

I tried to make a parallel version of MemberQ for use with a large list, but failed miserably in terms of performance. I used Partition to subdivide the list and ParallelMap to perform the MemberQ checks for each part:

```
ParallelMemberQ[list_,form_]:=Module[{n,plist},
    n=Quotient[Length[list],$KernelCount-1];
    plist=Partition[list,n,n,1,{}];
    Or@@ParallelMap[MemberQ[#, form] &, plist]
]

list=Table[i,{i,10^6}];
```

Testing:

```
AbsoluteTiming[ParallelMemberQ[list,123]]
```

> {0.293277,True}

```
AbsoluteTiming[MemberQ[list,123]]
```

> {0.0460892,True}

Any ideas if it is possible to make a faster parallel version of MemberQ?

(This code is poor since my partition of the list may leave very few elements to the last parallel kernel.)

Comment: I think the main problem is that this use of `Partition` unpacks the arrays. `PackedArrayQ/@plist` gives a list of `False` and `plist` itself is ragged, so that is also not a `PackedArray`. It is probably better to use `Partition` in such a way that it returns a proper 2d tensor.

Comment: Another issue is that `MemberQ` returns as soon as it finds one match.  Your parallel code goes through the whole list no matter what.

Comment: @Michael E2 - True. I knew it was a very poor algorithm and my hope was if someone could come with a good solution.

Comment: @Jacob - I think I'll need to research about packed arrays to understand that. Thanks.

Comment: If you have packed arrays and wish to check if the list contains a number equal to another, then the following will be fast: `Total[Unitize[list - 123]] < Length[list]`.  (See point 2.3 in this answer: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29351. Note also that `MemberQ` unpacks packed arrays, which wastes time.)

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [(41753)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41753/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think questions about parallelizing simple tasks are quite nice. We should be careful about not making duplicate (efforts in) answers though, as the link your provide is quite comprehensive. Maybe halirutan can make this into a nice example on how to use parallelize stuff.

Comment: @Jacob I think parallelization is important too; I proposing keeping this question but restricting its answers to parallel methods alone.  Add `Parallelization -> True` to your compiled method?

Comment: Another big bottleneck may be that when we use `ParallelMap`, the data in the list has to be made available to the other kernels. If this is done by copying the data, then we cannot really use this to make a competitive solution.

Comment: @Jacob It is sensible to leave this open for a while, but your answer does a good job in elucidating some approaches. In a few days, if nothing else appears, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 12):

If you are going to do a lot of membership tests on the same list it may be useful to look at `Dispatch`

On my virtual PC:

```
AbsoluteTiming[MemberQ[list, 123]]
```

> {0.163837, True}

```
dlist = Dispatch[list -> True // Thread];

TrueQ[1222000023 /. dlist] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.0000128508, False}

```
TrueQ[1223 /. dlist] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.0000243048, True}

So, this is more than 2000 times faster. It comes at a cost though, as `Dispatch` takes about 1.6 seconds to build.

Therefore, this method is more efficient than MemberQ if you need to do more than about 10 tests with the same list.

Comment: Very very nice. I'll try that.

Comment: In V10+, one can use `Association`, too.  See [Difference between Association and Dispatch](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69291/difference-between-association-and-dispatch).

Comment: @MichaelE2 Good call. Though it won't make much difference as far as timing is concerned.

Comment: For me, `Association` takes about 55-60% of the time, both in initial construction and in look-up; perhaps a medium sort of improvement.

Comment: Replacing `ReplaceAll` with `Replace` at level 1 will yield about the same reduction.

Comment: @MichaelE2 and Sjoerd some timing experiments here: [(41753)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41753/121), [(55980)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55980/121)

Comment: @mr.wiz ok, I must have missed that. Maybe we should close and /or merge.

Comment: Suppose we focus this Q&A *only* on parallel methods rather than other fast alternatives?

Comment: Ok_____________

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries perhaps you could add a little disclaimer that you do not address the issue of parallelization, while that subject is the reason the question is still open? Perhaps with a link to the other Q&A, or even a pointer to my answer? People like to vote for a "quick fix", but I feel information about parallelization should more visible (by upvotes or an accept). I would also be ok with merging our answers and deleting my own, or something similar. Feedback on my answer is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 8):

**Short answer**

It is not a good idea to make a parallel version of `MemberQ`. This is mainly because membership testing is generally faster than copying data and copying the data is necessary in *Mathematica* to allow other kernels to work with the data properly.

**About the rest of this answer**

This answer addresses some tricky stuff specific to the code presented by the OP. A timing comparison is made to show the limits of parallelization by means of distributing information across kernels. Some general considerations about membership testing are made, even though that is mostly duplicate information on this site. That information can be found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41753/4330), as noted by Mr.Wizard.

---

**PackedArrays and Parallelisation**

This section shows how to properly distribute data between kernels, even though that is a bad idea for this problem.

The code in the question does not make proper use of packed arrays. We see that `plist` as constructed below has the nice property of having packedarrays as elements.

```
Quiet@LaunchKernels[];
mm = 1234567;
list = Range@mm;
ll = mm;
{nn, rem} = QuotientRemainder[ll, $KernelCount];
firstLen = nn + rem;
prePlist = List @@ Partition[list[[firstLen + 1 ;;]], nn]; plist = 
 Prepend[prePlist, list[[;; firstLen]]];
Developer`PackedArrayQ /@ plist
```

> ```
> {True,True,True,True}
> ```

I now compare timings of the actual membership testing. The time to distribute the definitions is not included. I will use `MemberQ`, which is so slow that the overhead of parallelisation is quite negligible. Note that in particular `MemberQ` does not exploit the fact we have nice packedarrays. It turns out we are about 3 times as fast when parallelising, with a `$KernelCount` of 4. I also compare timings for the faster compiled version of `MemberQ`. Then parallelising gives only a minimal speedup.

```
intMemQ = 
  Compile[{{list, _Integer, 1}, {num, _Integer}}, 
   MemberQ[list, num]];
ParallelEvaluate[
  intMemQ = 
   Compile[{{list, _Integer, 1}, {num, _Integer}}, 
    MemberQ[list, num]]];
SetSharedVariable[plist];
ParallelEvaluate[localList = plist[[$KernelID]]];
Or @@ (Unevaluated@ParallelEvaluate@intMemQ[localList, mm] /. 
    OwnValues[mm]) // AbsoluteTiming
Or @@ (Unevaluated@ParallelEvaluate@MemberQ[localList, mm] /. 
    OwnValues[mm]) // AbsoluteTiming
intMemQ[list, mm] // AbsoluteTiming
MemberQ[list, mm] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.001864,True}
> {0.03453,True}
> {0.002047,True}
> {0.089282,True}
> ```

Let's set ourselves up for some more timings to see how long a complete procedure would take

```
paraMemQ[list_, kk_, func_] :=
  Module[{len, firstLen, prePlist, plist, nn, ll, rem, memships},
   Quiet@LaunchKernels[];
   ll = Length@list;
   {nn, rem} = QuotientRemainder[ll, $KernelCount];
   firstLen = nn + rem;
   prePlist = List @@ Partition[list[[firstLen + 1 ;;]], nn]; 
   plist = Prepend[prePlist, list[[;; firstLen]]];
   SetSharedVariable[plist];
   ParallelEvaluate[localList = plist[[$KernelID]]];
   memships = ParallelEvaluate[func[localList, kk]];
   UnsetShared[plist];
   Or @@ memships
   ];
```

If we restrict ourselves to `MemberQ`, even the full procedure of distributing definitions and determining membership turns out to be faster than using `MemberQ` on one kernel. However, if we use a better function than `MemberQ`, we are only slowing things down.

```
paraMemQ[list, mm, False &] // AbsoluteTiming
paraMemQ[list, mm, intMemQ] // AbsoluteTiming
paraMemQ[list, mm, MemberQ] // AbsoluteTiming
intMemQ[list, mm] // AbsoluteTiming
MemberQ[list, mm] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.056206,False}
> {0.057866,True}
> {0.080538,True}
> {0.001482,True}
> {0.087975,True}
> ```

I included `False &` to show a lower bound on the timing of the procedure, which arises from the time it takes to distribute definitions and other overhead.

Note that none of the differences in timing are explained by the ability of `MemberQ` to return a value before traversing the entire list, as we have constructed the list in such a way that only the last element matches.

**Membership tests on the same list**

The compiled version of `MemberQ` can be beaten. I have used it mostly for convenience in the previous section. In the present section, I will discuss some more ways to test membership. As mentioned before, this information can also be found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41753/4330).

One algorithm for membership testing is binary search, for which [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/72065/4330) is a nice starting point. Don't forget to `Sort` in that case.

If the range in which you search fits in memory you can do something like this.

```
lookup = ConstantArray[0, mm];
list = Union[RandomInteger[{1, mm}, Quotient[mm, 2]]];
lookup[[list]] = 1;
```

Doing `10^6` searches then does not take much time

```
numbersToLookup = RandomInteger[{1, mm}, 10^6];
AbsoluteTiming[Total@lookup[[numbersToLookup]]]
```

> ```
> {0.01414,394130}
> ```

In the last example we see that `394130` of the random integers was present in `list`.

If the range is too big, we can use the technique by Sjoerd, using `Dispatch`. In the example I tried it was slightly faster to use `Association`, as suggested by MichaelE2 in the comments.

```
mm2 = 10^10;
list2 = Union[RandomInteger[{1, mm2}, mm]];
dlist = Dispatch[Append[list2 -> True // Thread, _Integer -> False]];
assoc = Association[list2 -> 1 // Thread];
kk = 10^6;
numbersToLookup2 = RandomInteger[{1, mm2}, kk];
```

We can then compare

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 Length@Select[Replace[numbersToLookup2 , dlist, 1], Identity]]
AbsoluteTiming@Total@Lookup[assoc, numbersToLookup2, 0]
```

> ```
> {0.573736,101}
> {0.340388,101}
> ```

It turns out that these solutions are much faster than using `BinarySearch` from `` "Combinatorica`" `` or using `` System`Utilities`HashTable `` in this case.

Comment: Note: to obtain parallelization without having to copy the input, and to avoid `MemberQ` unpacking, one may use OpenMP in a LibraryLink function. The C code given [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87486/faster-binary-hamming-weight-for-big-integers) may be adapted straightforwardly for this question.