# Is there a practical way to define a default value for missing keys in an Association?

Tags: programming, associations

#### Clarification

Although I may be missing his point I currently feel that Leonid's comments below are misleading.  I am not looking for anything that is not already a part of `Association` functionality *other* than a way to define what is returned for a missing key on a per-association basis.  I thought that the `Block` example below made this clear but perhaps not.

I am seeking a way to do something like this:

```
asc = <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, _ -> 0|>;

asc["x"]

(* desired output: 0 *)

(* actual output: Missing["KeyAbsent", "x"] *)
```

Critically **I am *not* looking for general pattern matching of Key names** however; I *only* want a way to define one *default* value for missing keys.

---

#### Original ramblings

It can be very useful to define background or default value for an object that can be incremented or otherwise modified.  A simple (and for me, common) use is a counter:

```
count[_] = 0;

++count[#] & /@ {"a", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a"}
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4}
> ```

Since there are advantages to [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html) such as ease of copying and direct manipulation of keys and values I would like to port this method to new function.  However I cannot think of a clean, practical way to define a default.  (I consider directly overloading System functions such as `Increment` undesirable.)

I note that it *is* possible to increment a missing value and then clean it up afterward:

```
asc = <||>;

++asc[#] & /@ {"a", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a"} /. _Missing -> 0
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4}
> ```

This isn't really the same as setting a default value however and it limits the way this method can be used.  Somewhat better I think is to temporarily redefine `Missing`.  This at least gives values that are up-to-date while the operation is performed.

```
asc = <||>;

Block[{Missing},
  Missing["KeyAbsent", _] = 0;
  ++asc[#] & /@ {"a", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a"}
]

asc
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4}
>
> <|"a" -> 4, "b" -> 2|>
> ```

This could be packaged a bit more nicely but it still feels like a bit of a kluge.

Is there an approach I am failing to consider?  Or by some slim chance is there a hidden way to do this?

Comment: I think that by nature of associations (immutability, in the first place), mutating them in-place isn't by far as natural as mutating `DownValues`. And the fact that what you request is problematic in this approach is simply another facet of that: the ability to use defaults has been transferred from association itself to the `Lookup` function, but then `Lookup` can not be used to mutate things, bacause it knows nothing about where a given assoc is stored (and doesn't care about it). If you need mutation, why use associations? You can keep using `DownValues` in such cases.

Comment: Also the title seems to be a bit misleading currently: what you ask for is not just default, but *mutable* default - which makes quite a difference.

Comment: @Leonid (1) It may be *as natural* but the functionality exists and I see no reason not to *try* to use it.  I realize that ultimately performance issues may or may not limit use but I disagree that this is somehow an *inherent* limitation if I infer that correctly.  (2) Does the existence of special default handling in `Lookup` prevent other handling?  I wouldn't think so.  (3) Do all of the benefits of associations cease to exist for some reason?  Easy copying and manipulation of values, nested associations, etc. still apply do they not?

Comment: @Leonid Regarding the title I tried to see it from that perspective but I cannot.  The default value is not being changed; it is only being used in subsequent computations.  Maybe tomorrow I can bring some fresh eyes to it but at the moment it feels like you are critiquing a straw man.

Comment: I use `Lookup` precisely because there is no default.

Comment: @rcollyer That works in many cases but it prevents the (IMHO) *natural* use of operators such as `Increment` or `AddTo`.  I see no reason that a default in the `Association` and a specified default in `Lookup` cannot coexist.  Am I mistaken?

Comment: Allowing `Lookup` to supply a default when one existed within an `Association` would require some tighter knitting between the two, otherwise how would `Lookup` know when to supply its default?

Comment: @rcollyer You seem to be implying that `Lookup` doesn't already have this `knitting` but I believe it does; it is not relying on `Missing` to detect a missing value.  I believe it finds it directly.  I mean that `Lookup` is not doing something like `/. _Missing -> 0` in my second example.  What therefore is the complication?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Re: 1 - I largely answered this [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/55503/81), but to summarize, the main advantage of associations with respect to `DownValues` or ``System`Utilities`HashTable`` is that associations are immutable, *but* cheap to copy and modify. In the linked post I described why immutability is valuable (statelessness, garbage collection, etc). The ability to mutate assocs in place does exist (like with lists), but its support in the language is limited to very simple things like part assignments. Since there are no true references in Mathematica, ...

Comment: @Mr.Wizard ... most other functions working with assocs will not have the information about where a given assoc is stored (in which variable or variables), and will operate on assoc directly, producing new assoc or whatever. So, every time when you need to add mutability, you have to do some special tricks, like you did with `Missing`. There is simply no way for `Lookup`, for example, to do some in-place modifications related to the default value. So, my point has been that what you ask for would go into directions with very weak support from the core language, and would need more work then.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Re: (2): No, it doesn't, but `Lookup` is the only built-in function providing the default mechanism. One can surely implement one's own handling, but that would be more work, again (3).*"Do all of the benefits of associations cease to exist for some reason? Easy copying and manipulation of values, nested associations, etc. still apply do they not"* - yes, they do not apply any more as long as you want your assoc to be mutable and carry a state. That's precisely the point. You have to then define a new data type that would carry that state together with the assoc, and integrate ...

Comment: @Mr.Wizard  ... that new data type into the language. Quite possible, but a lot of work. I might post some version of such solution later, if I have the time. This brings us to an important topic of the lack of subtyping mechanism for core data structures in Mathematica - which would allow one to e.g. subtype an assoc and add some state to it (like one can do in e.g. Python).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Re - default value: indeed, you are right, it doesn't change. So, I take that critique back. In fact, one constructive suggestion that comes out of this is to be able to specify a default value, or generally, default *function*, when association is constructed. In fact, at some point during development such thing was discussed internally, but then for some reason it has been discarded. When I get a chance, I will ask, what was the rationale behind not having it.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard To add more to my argument, a principal difference between associations and (mutable) hash tables is that assocs can be used with functions like `Map` etc for data transformations, while hash tables can not, because they are stateful. Now, while we can define e.g. the semantics of `Map` acting on an assoc with a default: `Map[f, AssocWithDefault[assoc, default]] -> AssocWithDefault[Map[f,assoc], f[default]]`, what would we do with say `MapIndexed` (which is defined on assocs)? There are also other operators for which the semantics of an assoc with default isn't clear.

Comment: Valid question! It would be nice to be able to do something like: `asso /: asso[key_] := Lookup[asso, key, "NoAv"]`. P.s. I'd delete everything up to "clarification" :)

Comment: Not exactly what you ask for but might be interesting in the general context, try this : `asc = <||>;Query[++asc[#] & /@ # &]@{"a", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a"}`, compared to `asc = <||>; Query[++asc[#] & /@ # &, MissingBehavior -> None]@{"a", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a"}`. The default setting of [`MissingBehavior`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MissingBehavior.html) is `Automatic`.

Comment: Related: [(69291)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/69291/121)

Answer (score 6):

It seems to me that merely defining a global default value enables the kind of application for associations that you are discussing.

```
asc = <||>; $asc = 0;

(KeyExistsQ[#][asc] || (asc[#] = $asc); ++asc[#]) & /@ 
   {"a", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a"}
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4}
> ```

```
asc
```

> ```
> <|"a" -> 4, "b" -> 2|>
> ```

```
bsc = <||>; $bsc = 1;

(KeyExistsQ[#[[1]]][bsc] || (bsc[#[[1]]] = $bsc); bsc[#[[1]]] = bsc[#[[1]]] #[[2]]) & /@ 
   MapThread[Rule, {{"a", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a"}, Range[6]}]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 8, 15, 48}
> ```

```
bsc
```

> ```
> <|"a" -> 48, "b" -> 15|>
> ```

I am prepared to be instructed on how what I have presented here misses the point.

Comment: This is certainly a valid approach.  My issue with it is the extra code needed for every operation; `++asc[#]` becoming `(KeyExistsQ[#][asc] || (asc[#] = $asc); ++asc[#])` is a pretty bad hit to clean coding.  It would be possible to define new operators e.g. `associationIncrement` (possibly with a shorter name) that handle this but one loses commonality in code.  I don't know of any satisfying solution but that is why I posted the question.

Answer (score 2):

Simply:

```
asc["x"]/._Missing->0
```

Comment: I am aware of this approach.  In fact you will find that it is present in my question if you read it in detail.

Comment: Yes your are indeed: I am a little confused by your compound expression.