# Assigning values to association in DownValues

Tags: evaluation, associations, assignment, downvalues

Compare the following code:

```
Clear[t];
t = <||>;
t[2] = 1/2;
t[2]
```

with

```
Clear[t];
t[2] = <||>;
t[2][2] = 1/2;
t[2][2]
```

The first works and the second doesn't. And `AssociateTo[t[2], 2->1/2]` works. What is the difference of mechanism behind the two methods?

Comment: is there any good reason why you don't make `t` an `Association` in the first place also for case 2? `t=<||>;t[2] = <||>;t[2][2] = 1/2` works very nicely and seems the best fit as long as you use the downvalues of `t` as a hash table anyway...

Comment: @AlbertRetey Very interesting work-around!  Why don't you post that as an answer?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: thanks, just did that...

Comment: @AlbertRetey Thanks for your suggestion. I didn't use that because I need a default value for each association, and there is no trivial way to set a default value in an association.

Comment: while there is no default value for `Association` there is `Lookup` which lets you extract by key and give a default value when the key is not present. That will of course need adaption to the existing code, but it should provide the functionality you are searching for...

Comment: William I know that problem. :-/  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/87608/121  @Albert I find `Lookup` a pretty ugly work-around for the lack of a per-Association default.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: but that is something you have to address to WRI, wouldn't you? `Lookup` might be ugly, but at least the functionality it is there and works, and knowing that that is not always the case it is enough to make me happy :-).

Comment: @Albert But it only works "sort of" -- you have to know what *default value* to give it for each association, so you still have to store and retrieve that information somewhere, and it still does not really address the case I gave as an example in that question.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: sorry with "it works" I just meant that `Lookup` does what is documented. Of course there are use cases like the ones you mention where it isn't doing what is needed. I think it is still worth mentioning that `Lookup` exists and suggest to use it where appropriate, even if it doesn't cover every use case (and taste). That doesn't mean I wouldn't appreciate if WRI would provide an `Association` which supports defaults if that is possible...

Comment: @Albert Oh yes, of course.  I think I took your comment the wrong way, or responded poorly to it.  `Lookup` is very useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is nothing unique to `Association`; the same issue affects simple lists:

```
a[1] = {1, 2, 3};

a[1][[2]] = 7;
```

> Set::setps: a[1] in the part assignment is not a symbol. >>

For full examination of this problem see: [How to Set parts of indexed lists?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7214/121)

As you can see from the answers to that question there is no universally satisfying and clean solution.

You wrote: *"And `AssociateTo[t[2], 2->1/2]` works."*  On my system (v10.1.0) it does not:

```
t[2] = <||>;
AssociateTo[t[2], 2 -> 1/2]
```

> AssociateTo::rvalue: t[2] is not a variable with a value, so its value cannot be changed. >>

If this has been amended in more recent versions then I'd say it is the canonical solution to this problem.  For older versions there is this:

```
t[2] = <|t[2], 2 -> 1/2|>;

t[2]
```

> ```
> <|2 -> 1/2|>
> ```

Comment: Thanks! I am using version 11 and that AssociationTo worked. Perhaps you can try this on their free cloud platform. It is surprising that they changed design of part of the core language.

Comment: @WilliamRiddle I do not find that surprising as is not an incompatible change; rather it is an extension or bug-fix, depending on one's perspective.

Answer (score 4):

This does not exactly answer your question, but it indicates how you can avoid the problem you have detected in almost all use cases: using downvalues as a hashtable is possible and often recommended, but since version 10 we have `Association`s which were introduced exactly for that purpose, whereas the use of downvalues as a hashtable looks more like an accidential benefit of pattern matching optimizations. The problem you have indicated is actually one of the most convincing use cases that justify the addition of a fundamental new datatype to Mathematica after more than 20 years. This should work with any recent version:

```
ClearAll[t]
t=<||>
t[2]=<||>
t[2][2]=1/2
```