# Replace For with If in Mathematica way

Tags: performance-tuning, syntax, coding-style

I have this code:

```
elList = {"H", "C", "N", "O", "F", "Cl"};
els = {"Ca", "O", "C", "Si", "H"};
corr = ConstantArray[1.0, Length@els];
For[i = 1, i <= Length@els, i++,
 If[!MemberQ[elList, els[[i]]], corr[[i]] = 1.13];
 ]
```

What would be the best way to replace the loop, in other words, how to replace it in the Mathematica way?

My only idea was:

```
(MemberQ[elList, #] & /@ els) /. {True -> 1.0, False -> 1.13}
```

Is there a better way or other way?

Answer (score 11):

You can rewrite your idea using [`If`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/If.html) as follows:

```
If[MemberQ[elList, #], 1., 1.13] & /@ els
```

> ```
> {1.13, 1., 1., 1.13, 1.}
> ```

However you may find on larger problems that repetitive use of `MemberQ` is not as fast as you would like, so consider a hash table in the form of an [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html), or if using an older version of *Mathematica* a [`Dispatch`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dispatch.html) table.

Create a list of [`Rule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule.html) expressions using [`Thread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread.html):

```
rules = Thread[elList -> 1.0]
```

> ```
> {"H" -> 1., "C" -> 1., "N" -> 1., "O" -> 1., "F" -> 1., "Cl" -> 1.}
> ```

Convert into optimized forms with [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html) or [`Dispatch`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dispatch.html)

```
asc = Association[rules];

disp = Append[rules, _ -> 1.13] // Dispatch;
```

Apply the hash tables:

```
Lookup[asc, els, 1.13]

Replace[els, disp, {1}]
```

> ```
> {1.13, 1., 1., 1.13, 1.}
>
> {1.13, 1., 1., 1.13, 1.}
> ```

- Note: in [`Lookup`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Lookup.html) the third parameter specifies the default value; in [`Replace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Replace.html) the third parameter is the [*levelspec*](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29750/121) on which to operate.

Recommended reading:

- [Fastest way to check for List membership](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41753/121)
- [Is there a faster way to Map an Association?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55980/121)
- [Difference between Association and Dispatch](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/69291/121)

Answer (score 1):

If speed is not you concern, may be this can be worth a try

```
common = Intersection[elList, els];
u = Map[ Position[els, # ] &, common ] ;
corr[[ Flatten[u] ]] = 1.13
```

This can be fit in a single line, and is almost readable

```
corr[[ Flatten[ Position[els, # ] & /@ Intersection[elList, els] ] ]] = 1.13
```

and will seem even more nice if you use (elList esc inter esc els) in place of Intersection[elList,els] - the parentheses around the intersection are required, the precedence of Intersection in operator form seems to be low.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little one-liner without `If`, probably not fast on large lists:

```
corr = (! MemberQ[elList, #] & /@ els) /. {True -> 1.13, False -> 1.0}
```